# RemoteDisconnected from celery task on docker when calling long running endpoints

Tags: django, docker, google-cloud-platform, celery, google-cloud-run

I have a Django application running on `docker-compose`. In one of my background celery task, I am calling a Cloud Run endpoint. This endpoint takes a long time to complete: 60-80 seconds.

```
celery task -- request -> Cloud Run
                         ... process ...
celery task <- response - Cloud Run
```

I have confirmed on Cloud Run that the time out is set to 300 seconds, but I am seeing that the Celery task is raising `('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))`.

Even when the Cloud Run itself is returning 200, my task is raising this error. Checking the logs on the celery side, I see that this error is raised when 61 seconds has passed from when the request was made.

Is there a configuration on some layer that is terminating my request? I checked that the `requests` module itself does not a timeout unless specified, so I am suspecting something else.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently NordVPN on my local machine was the problem. Once I shut it down I stopped seeing this error.